# Show full sidebar menu in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap, things are normal in full screen mode but in the mobile mode, if the page content large, the full side bar is shown, but for short page content, some sidebar contents are hidden, refer the image for better understanding [Not full sidebar menu is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwbdk.jpg)

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Here is my part of the code https://jsfiddle.net/rrn4bvqm/

Comment: You need to paste you html  as well, otherwise we won't be able to help you :)

Comment: check it now i have included html too

Comment: Can't see any HTML code in your fiddle

Comment: Your fiddle without HTML